# unable to run clownfish for skype

Tags: linux, libraries, parrotsec, wxwidgets

i installed clownfish from https://clownfish-translator.com/linux.html and i tried to install all libraries and after installation the application shows in menu but it's not working and after that i tried to run it from storage through terminal

```
./ClownfishEvolution: error while loading shared libraries: libwx_gtk2u_unofficial_richtext-3.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

i don't know what to do now.

Comment: See if that shared library is available from the packaging system. On Debian/Ubuntu it's `dpkg -S libwx_gtk2u_unofficial_richtext-3.0.so.0`

Comment: no it's not available and i guess its a package from codelite